# Regex for a repeating pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am trying to create a regex to validate a string. The string could be of the following formats (to give an idea of what I am trying to do here):

145/1/3 or

748/57676/6765/454/345 or

45/234 45/235 45/236

So basically the string can contain numbers, spaces and forward slashes and the string can end with a number only. I am new at regex and have gone through many of the questions on the website. But please you have to admit that this is really confusing and difficult to master. And if someone could refer an author or any weblink that can teach regex, that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance mates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this

```
^[0-9]( |[0-9]|\/)*[0-9]$
```

And used [this](http://regexr.com/394vl) to test it.

You can see it matches anything that begins (^) with a number, has zero or more (*) of either a space, a number or (|) a forward-slash (/) and ends ($) with a number.

Now that I am aware that the space and `/` cannot go together and multiple spaces and/or slashes are also not allowed, this RegEx is a better fit for you.

```
^[0-9]+([ \/][0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: @KonradKokosa  Why shouldn't it match that?

Comment: This works properly for me - unless OP doesn't want a space succeeding a slash

Comment: He didn't say he didn't, so perhaps he should clarify.

Comment: Hey guys sorry I forgot about that part. And yes, the slash and space were not supposed to be together. This one worked just perfect. Thanks a lot Matt! I desperately wanna learn regex. Can you suggest some article or video or anything?

Comment: @PrashantTiwari   I learned much of my RegEx knowledge from [this](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm) site. And I agree with you, RegEx can be a challenge to master.  Good luck!

Comment: @PrashantTiwari how? this matches `748/4/57676/ 6765/454/345` which is wrong along your saying "the slash and space were not supposed to be together"...

Comment: @Konrad Kokosha : Thanks for your help mate..actually its 748/57676/6765/454/345 and not 748/4/57676/ 6765/454/345. If you look at the question closely, I did not put the space in that string. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\d(\d|\s|\/)*\d$
```

`\d` = digit character (you can also use `[0-9]`).
`\s` = space character
The brackets followed by a star means to repeat a `\d`, `\s`, or `/` an infinite amount of times.
The final `\d$` means the ending must match a digit.

Comment: This will not work for `748/57676/ 6765/454/345` - not sure if it enough for OP.

Comment: I think you need to escape the `/` and he said it needed to end with a number, so append a `$`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `^[/\d\s]*\d$`.

It is looking for the beginning of the string `^` , then 0 or more digits, spaces `[/\d\s]*` followed by a digit `\d` then the end of the string `$`.

Comment: @Konrad so just to make sure I understand: each space separated group of numbers and /s must end with a number, not just the entire string must end with a number?

Comment: So I understand the question but this is question to OP I believe.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this meets what the asker was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use following regular expression:

```
(\d+(/\d+)*\s*)+
```

This mean: some digits (`\d+`) followed by optional repeating pattern of some digits and `\` (`(/\d+)*`) followed by an optional number of whitespaces (`\s*`), all repeated at least once.

Comment: He said it needed to end in a number.

Comment: @MattCremeens, ask him, not me... Then we will now who is right.

Comment: I don't need to ask him. It's already in his question: `...and the string can end with a number only.`

Comment: @MattCremeens, examples provided by him suggests something else. So do not be so sure.